# ELF shared library portability

Tags: shared-libraries, elf

Imagine that I have shared library in ELF format which exports only one determined symbol(entry point) with determined calling convention and imports no symbols at all.

Will be I able to dlopen/dlsym/dlclose this shared library among different UNIX flavors(Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will be I able to dlopen/dlsym/dlclose this shared library among different UNIX flavors(Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris)?

Assuming your library is completely self-contained and does not call any external routines, nor issues any system calls ... the answer is still no.

In the ELF header `e_ident[EI_OSABI]` byte, you will have one of `ELFOSABI_GNU`, `ELFOSABI_FREEBSD`, or `ELFOSABI_SOLARIS`. The loader will (or at least should) reject attempts to `dlopen` the library built for the "wrong" OS.

However, if you patch that one byte to match the current OS, then `dlopen` would likely work.

Answer (score 0):

No, the ELF loader and convention of the ELF files differs across operating systems, as well as the syscalls that are used to interact with the kernel.

You *could* edit the file to change the loader so that the FreeBSD or Solaris loader accepted it, and if you only use the most minimal subse it *might* load but it's very unlikely you'd be able to get much out of it, unless it's just a blob of pure functions.

Comment: There no any external symbols or syscalls inside shared library. Only userspace code.

Comment: "userspace code" is… more than vague. Calling syscalls *is* userspace code. If it's just data processing functions (as I said, pure functions) it might work with enough massaging. But if anything depends on shared state of any kind, it's unlikely to work at all. Except maybe on FreeBSD since it has (had?) the ability to load Linux ELF files to begin with.

Comment: You are absolutely true regarding that sysenter/trap/whatever instructions are available in ring2/nonprivileged code. To be more clear - I mean that code inside shared library is totally self contained - there are no calls outside.